# How to send "token" to "Api" in "react"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

I'm a new developer.
If you login to our website, JWT will be created.
When I press the button, I have to put it in the API as a backend.
And if the screen is successful, the address in the API must be printed out.
If it fails, 'authentication failure' should be displayed on the screen.
I want to do this. Please help me.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@material-ui/core';

function TestPage() {
  const onLogin = () => {
    var variables = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
    };

    Axios.post('/auth/login', variables).then((res) => {
      setCookie('token', res.payload.accessToken);
      setCookie('exp', res.payload.accessTokenExpiresIn);
      Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${res.payload.accessToken}`;
      Axios.get('/user/me').then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          style={{ width: '200px' }}
          onClick={(e) => customFetch(e)}>
          address
        </Button>
      </div>
      {address && <div>{address}</div>}
    </>
  );
}

export default TestPage;
```

Comment: hi, what do you mean by "address in the API must be printed out". Also to check for errors you can use a `try, catch` block.

Comment: @Muljayan Currently, the value 'address' exists in the API. 
This value should be shown on the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally for any network operation, it's helpful to know when it's in progress, has finished, and/or has an error. Let's set this up:

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
const [data, setData] = useState(null)
const [error, setError] = useState(null)

// inside your `onLogin` function...
setIsLoading(true);
Axios.post('/auth/login', variables).then((res) => {
  setCookie('token', res.payload.accessToken);
  setCookie('exp', res.payload.accessTokenExpiresIn);
  Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${res.payload.accessToken}`;
  // bit messy using the same error state for both but you can always refactor
  Axios.get('/user/me').then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        setData(res); // not sure where the actual data is with Axios
  }).catch(err => setError(err);
}).catch(err => setError(err));
setIsLoading(false);
```

During your POST, set the state variables accordingly:

1. Before the post, `setIsLoading(true)`
2. On success, `setData(response.data) // whatever your payload might be`
3. On error/failure, `setError(error)`

Now in your component return, you can conditionally render your different states, e.g:

```
// your component body
if (isLoading) return (
  // a loading state
)
if (error) return (
  // an error state
  // e.g. "Authentication Failure"
)
return (
  // your success/ideal state
  // e.g:
  <>
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        style={{ width: '200px' }}
        onClick={(e) => customFetch(e)}>
        address
      </Button>
    </div>
    {address && <div>{address}</div>}
  </>
)
```

Alternatively, you could leverage the variables slightly differently:

```
return (
  <>
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        style={{ width: '200px' }}
        onClick={(e) => customFetch(e)}
        disabled={isLoading}>
        address
      </Button>
    </div>
    <div>
      {isLoading
        ? 'Checking...'
        : error !== null
        ? 'Something went wrong'
        : 'Ready to submit'}
    </div>
  </>
)
```

The ternary style can be a bit messy though.